# many systemd-udevd spawns on embedded device

Tags: systemd, udev

On my embedded device I observe a lot of systemd-udevd processes. Every few minutes a new systemd-udevd is spawning. At the same time a usb device (GSM Module) gets recognized and disconnect a few seconds later (hardware issue). Is this a normal behavior of systemd-udev?

Answer (score 0):

`systemd-udevd` listens to kernel uevents. For every event,`systemd-udevd` executes matching instructions specified in `udev` rules.May be you are frequently getting the kernel uevents and it is causing `systemd-udevd` to execute the instructions.

Some tips:

Check your udev rules in `/etc/udev/` and try to update your `initramfs`.